# Will replacing 4 GB DDR3 ram (2GB+2GB) with 10 GB DDR3 ram (8GB+2GB) work with Intel i3 processor?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, performance, upgrade

I have system with Intel i3 processor, 4 GB DDR3 ram (2GB+2GB). I am thinking to expand ram with buying 8GB DDR3 ram. Will Intel i3 processor work with configuration of 10 GB DDR3 ram (8GB+2GB)?

What factors or configurations related to RAM or motherboard should I check with before configuring system with 10 GB DDR3 ram (8GB+2GB)?

Comment: Your motherboard manual will indicate if this configuration is supported.

Comment: @Ramhound, Funny thing, I will need to find manual first.  God knows where it is now :D

Comment: Just download it from the manufacturer.

Comment: What is the model of your i3 processor? Also, more importantly what is the model of your motherboard?